# Evenly separate radio buttons using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My radio buttons are too close together and I would like them to evenly be displayed across the row using the bootstrap grid system. Any idea's on how I can accomplish this?[image]

```
    <div class="radio">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
           <label>
             <input id="visitors_radio" name="user[role]" type="radio">
             Visitors
           </label>
           <label>
             <input id="staff_radio" name="user[role]" type="radio">
             Staff
           </label>
           <label>
             <input id="volunteer_radio" name="user[role]" type="radio">
             Volunteer
           </label>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? Maybe CSS has something for that to generate space around elements? What you think?

Comment: Probably! I just got to this and I'm trying to build my score/familiarize myself with Stackoverflow. Also, I think bootstrap can do it and that may be a bit cleaner?

Comment: But that's a good way to learn: trying different things :)

Comment: For sure! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="radio">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <label>
         <input id="visitors_radio" name="user[role]" type="radio">
         Visitors
       </label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <label>
         <input id="staff_radio" name="user[role]" type="radio">
         Staff
       </label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <label>
         <input id="volunteer_radio" name="user[role]" type="radio">
         Volunteer
       </label>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Make use of the bootstrap grid to help you to achieve that.